# How to find out the reason for high energy and cpu impact?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, cpu-usage

I wondering about my nearly finished app. It causing a CPU usage of always above 100% and my iPhone getting very hot even if it don't do anything.

My app just loading some json from the internet and displays that with some images and text. At the beginning I had a spinning image for showing loading process and thats nearly it.

I dont know how to find the part causing the usage.

[image]

Here are the two bad guys, but I don't know what they do and where they come from:

[image]

It's so wired, my mainView is a Tableview, if I do nothing I have that over 100% cpu usage, if I scroll up and down, it drops down to 70%/80%.

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringCPUUse.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringCPUUse.html)

Comment: Did you jailbreak your phone?

Comment: @Lion I already read that article, doesn't helped me.

Comment: Hi there - are you using threading? From the screenshot above maybe the main queue is being overloaded.

Comment: Yeah I think so. I used this "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in completion()..}" for HTTP requests and loading images but no where else.

Comment: By measuring the performance with Instruments (as described in the referenced article), it is definitely possible to locate the problem. If you're not yet experienced with Instruments, ask the questions that help you to use the tool effectively.

Comment: BTW: As the CPU load decreases during scrolling, you likely have a sort of infinite loop with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...`, i.e. you immediately submit something from the completion handler. (Scrolling pauses most submitted tasks on the main queue.)

Comment: Oh okay, yes! That makes totally sense. But my cells don't have any action in it. Just Imageviews and buttons. So why should CPU drops when nothing changes.

Comment: I tested out. Makes my array of cells empty so my tableView is just empty, nothing changed, still over 100%

Comment: Because you sad I should ask the question that help me use that instruments tool better. Is there not the possibility to show me the method or at least the class that uses my CPU or from which class each thread is coming? Something like that?

Comment: Okay, found it. It was that never ending spinning image on the loadscreen. I thought it stops itself because the instance of the loadingcontroller not used anymore. Did I delete them by myself? I have no reference anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you said

> At the beginning I had a spinning image for showing loading process

this is the key, even though you remove, hide or whatever you do to hide the spinning image, but seems like you're not  stopping if from animating (spinning) , make sure the spinning image stops spinning animation befor hiding it

Comment: Yes I have done this now. But I wondering, should that instance of my LoadingController not be deleted from swifts "garbageCollector" after going to my mainView? I have no reference or something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did to hide it from the user, but even though the container view has called viewDidDisappaer ,you did not tell the operating system that I don't want that spinning view anymore, you maybe just hided it, in this case operating system considers this spinning view as something you want hidden only, but to be still spinning even though it's hidden

Comment: Can I force deleting it because of memory?

Comment: you don't need to, just make sure it's not animating "spinning"

Comment: to anyone reading this, I ended up having an infinite loop. Was using good ole recursion to keep an image spinning and wasn't handling it properly